# How to stop resizing div element when it reaches the specific width?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried to make a site with a resizable sidebar using `jquery-resizable.js`. What I want to do is making stop resizing once it reaches the specific width. However, it keeps moving even though it is already over the min-width value. I found the `ResizeObserver` to detect the changing width values and tried to change the div element's CSS values like `resize:none;` but it didn't work.

**How could I stop resizing once it reaches a certain width value?**

Here are my codes.

```js
$(".panel-left").resizable({
    handleSelector: ".splitter",
    resizeHeight: false,
    resizeHeightFrom:'center',
});

var ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const cr = entry.contentRect;
    console.log('Element:', entry.target);
    console.log(`Element size: ${cr.width}px x ${cr.height}px`);
    console.log(`Element padding: ${cr.top}px ; ${cr.left}px`);

    if (cr.width <= 330) {
      console.log("its too small");
      cr.css('resize', 'none');
    }
  }
});

ro.observe(document.querySelector('.panel-right'));
```

```css
.panel-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 900px;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    min-width: 650px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #8E44AD;
    color: white;
}

.panel-right {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    min-width: 350px;
    background: #34495E;
    color: #fff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.splitter {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 8px;
    background: url(images/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #ccc;
    min-height: 100%;
    cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Generate-Resizable-DOM-Elements-Resizable/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

<div class="panel-container el" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="panel-left resizable">
        left panel
    </div>

    <div class="splitter">
    </div>

    <div class="panel-right" id="panelRight">
        right panel
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for max-width not min-width. With min-width you're setting the smallest it can be, with max-width you're setting the largest it can possibly be.

Comment: Oh, I thought with the min-width, I could limit the width. But it was the max-width. But then, I set the max-width to the right and left both, but the right div still can move. What could I do?

Comment: You're using display flex on the parent. Without assigning a justify-content value for the parent then the items will always fill the available space. Here's the options you have [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087262/jquery-ui-resizable-stop-resizing-in-the-resize-event

Answer (score 2):

What you try do do is possible with `max-width` like @JHeth mentioned.

You can set the `min-width` to set the minimum width of your div and `max-width` to stop on the pixel size you want.

```
.panel-left {
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

See the example below:

```js
$(".panel-left").resizable({
    handleSelector: ".splitter",
    resizeHeight: false,
    resizeHeightFrom:'center',
});
```

```css
.panel-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.panel-left {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #8E44AD;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
}

.panel-right {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #34495E;
    color: #fff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.splitter {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 8px;
    background: url(images/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #ccc;
    min-height: 100%;
    cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Generate-Resizable-DOM-Elements-Resizable/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

<div class="panel-container el" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="panel-left resizable">
        left panel
    </div>

    <div class="splitter">
    </div>

    <div class="panel-right" id="panelRight">
        right panel
    </div>
</div>
```